# Suitecrm Workflow - Email sending using varchar custom field option

Tags: suitecrm

I have a problem with the action of sending email to an email address entered in a varchar field. The option called ‘field’ in the action seems not to work. Can anyone help me understand what is entered as a parameter? I have already tried to insert several references to the field but without success.

[Suitecrm workflow screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdCgF.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That option has an internal name of Record Field. I looked in the code and I don't think that option is implemented yet.

The Email addresses are stored in a specific module called Email Addresses. This module has different functionalities, such as the opt-in or rejected options. And it has a relationship by default with the modules Users, Contacts, Accounts, Leads.

I don't think SuiteCRM can send an email using the address from a text box.